# Will the destructor of the base class called if an object throws an exception in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Will the destructor of the base class be called if an object throws an exception in the constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If an exception is thrown during construction, all previously constructed sub-objects will be properly destroyed. The following program proves that the base is definitely destroyed:

```
struct Base
{
    ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "destroying base\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "throwing in derived constructor\n";
        throw "ooops...";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Derived x;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

output:

```
throwing in derived constructor
destroying base
```

(Note that the destructor of a native pointer does nothing, that's why we prefer RAII over raw pointers.)

Comment: I can't remember - if you hadn't caught the exception, is the base class destructor guaranteed to be called, or does that count as part of "stack unwinding" and hence it's implementation-defined whether it occurs or not on an uncaught exception?

Comment: @Steve: Without the catch, the base is not destroyed on my implementation, so I *guess* it's not guaranteed, but who knows... :-)

Comment: Which is why it is a good idea to put a catch and re-throw in main to force the stack to be unwound correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The rule is that every object whose constructor has finished successfully will be destructed upon exception. E.g:

```
class A {
public:
    ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { throw 0; }
    ~B() {}
};
```

~A() is called. ~B() is not called;

EDIT: moreover, suppose you have members:

```
struct A {
    A(bool t) { if(t) throw 0; }
    ~A() {}
};

struct B {
    A x, y, z;
    B() : x(false), y(true), z(false) {}
};
```

What happens is: x is constructed, y throws, x is destructed (but neither y nor z).

Answer (score 6):

From Standard docs, *15.3 - 11*,

> The **fully constructed base classes and members of an object shall be destroyed** before entering the handler of a function try-
>   block of a constructor or destructor for that object.

Comment: Nice quote, but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

When an exception is thrown, the ***destructors are called for*** all (sub-) ***objects whose constructors were successfully run***. This extends to data members and base classes alike.

For example, for this code

```
struct base {};

struct good {};

struct bad {
  bad() {throw "frxgl!";}
};

struct test : public base {
  std::string s;
  good g;
  bad b;
  test() {}
};
```

before `test`'s constructor is executed, first the constructor for the base class is called, then the constructors for `s`, `g`, and `b`. Only if these finish successfully, the constructor for `test` is executed. When the exception is thrown during the construction of `b`, the base class constructors as well as the constructors for the data members `s` and `g` have been fully executed, so their destructors are run. The constructor of `test` itself and of `b` have not been run successfully, so their destructors are not run.